# To make a cream cheese icing, can I use cottage cheese?

Tags: substitutions, icing

Can I use cottage cheese instead of cream cheese to make a carrot cake icing?

Comment: I don't know for sure, which is why I'm commenting and not answering, but it seems to me that the higher moisture content of cottage cheese compared to cream cheese would be a problem when making icing.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that you can use the cottage cheese, you could even use ricotta cheese which Italians have a Ricotta Cheese Pie and Sambucca Liqueur is used as a flavoring.  It is delicious.  Using cottage cheese, which I have, really does not taste good, not only in my opinion but others who have tried to cut calories.  Either use less cream cheese with less powdered sugar and no butter for the frosting or just dust it with the powdered sugar.  The first answer is correct, yes you can, but the taste ruins your carrot cake no matter how finely you blend it. So my answer is no, don't do it.    Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

I actually used cottage cheese for a pound cake frosting, because I had no cream cheese. I took the cake to church, and everyone loved it. Do not use the same amount of cottage cheese ( use 1 1/2 cups instead of 2 cups), puree the cottage cheese in a blender, then add other ingredients. I chopped strawberries and added them to the frosting, to increase the flavor.

Answer (score 1):

I have also used cottage cheese in place of cream cheese. The end result was just fine. It's fine to say "use cream cheese", but when one has a milk allergy, something has to take it's place.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how a milk allergy is addressed by replacing one milk product with another.

Answer (score 0):

You can, yes and you use the same amount as you would cream cheese.

Refs:

- http://ni.lovefoodhatewaste.com/node/1414
- http://dish.allrecipes.com/common-ingredient-substitutions/

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can BUT, your final product will suffer greatly. I'm a professional Pastry Chef and wouldn't consider doing it for any reason.

Comment: How will it suffer? Texture, flavor, both?

Comment: The texture is less solid because of the curds in the cottage cheese broken down compared to a solid mass of cream cheese so it is more runny or watery when blended and no matter how much powdered sugar you put in it to add flavor and tighten it up, it is nasty and too much sugar can happen. I then add vanilla and even pineapple chunks or crushed and it becomes a mess.  Flavor, texture, presentation and most of all taste is awful.  Not worth it.  Also as a note, if you make it a 2 or 3 layer cake, it will not stand up, it falls down even if you put in the fridge it will not set up.